# Is there a difference between a variable with a ? or undefined type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, undefined

In Typescript there are two different methods of saying that a property can be `undefined` when creating an interface:

Method 1:

```
interface m1 {
    prop?: randomType; // type is (randomType | undefined)
}
```

Method 2:

```
interface m2 {
    prop: randomType|undefined; // type is (randomType | undefined)
}
```

The only immediately apparent between these two that I have noticed is that when hovering over `prop` IntelliSense will show `undefined` in blue for Method 1 and green for Method 2.

Are there any other differences between these?

Comment: The second method will set a prop to value `randomType`, or `undefined` if randomType doesn't exist. The question mark on the other hand marks a field as optional.

Comment: @JLCarveth Thanks for the response, so the only difference would be that the first one will allow you to implement the interface without declaring a variable at all, where as the second one forces you to declare a variable, but if you declare it as undefined the created object is identical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make it simple : with `?` the field becomes optional :

```
type randomType = {}

interface M1 {
  prop?: randomType; // type is (randomType | undefined)
}

interface M2 {
  prop: randomType | undefined; // type is (randomType | undefined)
}

const m1: M1 = {} // OK
const m2: M2 = {} // NOK
const m22: M2 = { prop: undefined } // OK
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBATghgOwCYHsC2AVc0C8UDeAvgLABQZAlgsBDAGZwDG0AsgIwFlRRgwpgB+AFyxEqTNgDcUAPQyooSFAoBnKAAp4ydFiUAfKAFdkEOlQhIAlGRLlSVGvSasATJ1Lde-EVvG7oBsZIpuZI0nIK2MpqmmI6UYEmZggW1qS2ZIwoCCrAUGhsIuxQeESy8gDyANKZ2bn5LkVupYTlUABy1bU5eWgujVAszQQ8fGAiQSEpSFCtEdVAA)

Comment: So in practice the only advantage to using the format in `M2` would be that it could be less error prone in certain cases?  But there are no cases where you absolutely need to use `M2`. And once the interfaces are implemented the objects are identical?

Comment: I like `M2` very much in case of refactoring, you'll never forget a key. For example if you really don't want to forget to set prop to random type. (Pretty usefull on big objects/types)